# Conflicting package versions / dependencies in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I installed empyrial package by

```
python3 -m pip install empyrial
```

in my virtual environment which i activated

at end of installation i receive a warning :

```
 ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pandas-profiling 3.6.1 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.16.0, but you have numpy 1.24.1 which is incompatible.
numba 0.54.1 requires numpy<1.21,>=1.17, but you have numpy 1.24.1 which is incompatible.
```

Few questions and doubts on this :

1. does this mean that numba , pandas profiling wont work without the necessary dependancies as the versions installed in the virutal environment are incompatible.
2. what is the workaround solution for this if we wish to use the installed version as well as install and fit the required version of the package for other respective packages to work and not produce an error in my python code ( s empyrial requires a certain version but scikit-learn, fbprophet and etc packages may require other versions)

I have tried seeing other solutions : they had the answer such as -

1. You can rename the package
2. You can change the installation path

What is the best solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle 1) is to downgrade/upgrade packages to get a suitable version for your other dependencies. For 2), unfortunately, there is no clean way of doing this in Python at the moment.

Other solutions you mentioned gave you the right idea.
Your best bet is to install both versions manually, by putting them in your Python path with a different name. Keep in mind that you will also have to rename one of them in imports for other libraries.

I would first figure out if you can downgrade other packages like fbprophet to accept the lower version of dependencies( scikit-learn) that will still work for empyrial, and only then resort to manual installation and library modification.

Comment: "Keep in mind that you will also have to rename one of them in imports for other libraries. " How do i do that ? I might try manual installation to resolve the conflict but just want to know while importing the library in python script in my project notebook should I import it as `import alterednameofpkg ` , please guide me

Comment: Let's say you have packages A and B, where B is the old version of package required by A.
So what you can do is download A and B into a separate folder in your project instead of using pip (from source), or you can use --target flag to  set dir to do it with pip. Then you rename B so it doesn't conflict with other newer versions by the same name, simply try renaming the folder B->Bmod, this should work unless there is an explicit name declaration. Then in your A package folder replace imports of B with Bmod. You can only do it for scripts in A from which you use the functions and classes.

Comment: @swagdevotee008 if the answer helped, please kindly mark it.